# Optional mutate in a function R

Tags: r, function, dplyr

This is my data:

```
data <- data.frame(school_type = c("nursery", "nursery", "nursery", "nursery", "primary", "primary", "primary", "primary"), 
                   staff_type = c("manager", "manager", "teacher", "teacher", "manager", "manager", "teacher", "teacher"),
                   age_group = c("20-30","30-40","20-30","30-40","20-30","30-40","20-30","30-40"), 
                   number_staff = c(40, 10, 20, 30, 40, 10, 20, 30)
```

| school_type | staff_type | age_group | number_staff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| nursery | manager | 20-30 | 40 |
| nursery | manager | 30-40 | 10 |
| nursery | teacher | 20-30 | 20 |
| nursery | teacher | 30-40 | 30 |
| primary | manager | 20-30 | 40 |
| primary | manager | 30-40 | 10 |
| primary | teacher | 20-30 | 20 |
| primary | teacher | 30-40 | 30 |

I have this function:

```
my_function <- function(group1 = NULL, 
                        group2 = NULL,
                        nongroup = NULL){
  
data1 <- data %>%
         group_by({{group1}}, {{group2}} ) %>%
         summarise(number_staff = sum(number_staff, na.rm = T)) %>%
         mutate({{nongroup}} := "Total")
                                          
return(data1)
}
```

Example 1: This runs fine:

```
x <- my_function(group1 = school_type,
                 group2 = staff_type,
                 nongroup = age_group)
```

Example 2: However when I don't have the "nongroup" argument, e.g. I leave it as NULL, it does not work. This is the argument used in the mutate:

```
y <- my_function(group1 = school_type,
                 group2 = staff_type,
                 nongroup = NULL)
```

It gives this  error:

*Error in `quos()`:
! The LHS of `:=` must be a string or a symbol
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.*

For this function, in some instances of its use, I want it to add an extra column (like in example 1) but in some instances of its use, I don't want it add the extra column (which is why in example 2 I left the argument as NULL).

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Do it in two steps.  First `summarise`.  Then test to see if `nongroup` is `NULL`.  If so, do nothing.  If not, perform the `mutate`.

Comment: PS.  It would be better style to make `data` a parameter to the function.  It will then generalise.  Also, if you make it the first parameter, then you can easily use your functions in a pipe.  But don't call the parameter `data`.  That clashes with a built-in function and may lead to confusion.

Comment: @Limey - so put the mutate bit in an if statement?

Also thanks for the heads up about use of data and also putting into the parameter!

Comment: "So put the mutate bit in an if statement?": exactly so.  And you're welcome.

Comment: an `if` statement, likely with intermediate assignment, such as : `data1 <- data %>% group_by(..) %>% summarize(..); if (!is.null(nongroup)) data1 <- mutate(data1, ..);`

Comment: Very hacky but you could use `mutate(data1, !!as_label(enquo(nongroup)) := "total")`. When `nongroup = NULL` the column is named "NULL". Also not supplying your data as the first arg, let alone no arg is asking for quosure hell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things get a bit messy when using non-standard evaluation like this, but this should work

```
my_function <- function(group1 = NULL, 
                        group2 = NULL,
                        nongroup = NULL){
  
  data %>%
    group_by({{group1}}, {{group2}} ) %>%
    summarise(number_staff = sum(number_staff, na.rm = T)) %>%
    {
      nongroup <- rlang::enquo(nongroup)
      if (!rlang::quo_is_null(nongroup)) {
        mutate(., !!nongroup := "Total")
      } else {
        .
      }
    } 
}
```

We need to explicitly turn `nongroup` into a quosure in order to test for NULL-ness without explicitly evaluating it. This means we can't use the `{{}}` embrace syntax in that case. Here we pipe into a `{}` block so we can use the `.` explicitly in the chain. This would allow you to pipe the result into more chain statements.

Tested with

```
my_function(group1 = school_type,
            group2 = staff_type,
            nongroup = age_group)
#   school_type staff_type number_staff age_group
#   <chr>       <chr>             <dbl> <chr>    
# 1 nursery     manager              50 Total    
# 2 nursery     teacher              50 Total    
# 3 primary     manager              50 Total    
# 4 primary     teacher              50 Total    

my_function(group1 = school_type,
            group2 = staff_type,
            nongroup = NULL)

#   school_type staff_type number_staff
#   <chr>       <chr>             <dbl>
# 1 nursery     manager              50
# 2 nursery     teacher              50
# 3 primary     manager              50
# 4 primary     teacher              50
```